# Why do modern MRI scanners use an axial static field?

Tags: medical-devices

Last night I was reading some fascinating [history of the first full-body MRI scanner](http://web.archive.org/web/20130121073127/http://www.mri.jhu.edu/~edelstei/Edelstein.Aberdeen.pdf) and noticed that it's fundamentally different from modern scanners in one particular way: the static B field is vertical, while all the modern machines I've seen pictures of strongly suggest a static B field parallel to the patient's axis.

Is there a reason why most modern machines orient their static field along the patient's axis and not through their frontal plane - was that first scanner's vertical field a non-fatal "mistake"?

Are there implications for image quality depending on which slice is selected, or is there a limitation on which slices *can* be selected? Are axial slices (which I imagine to be what modern machines optimize for) perhaps more commonly useful than frontal slices?

Edit: I don't know why this was migrated without conferring with me. This question is about the *application* of these scanners, i.e. what **medical** diagnostic reasons are there to prefer one slice orientation over another. Clearly engineering issues impose constraints on what medical professionals can do, and I'm interested in those too, but I want this to be primarily about what these machines *do* (specifically with humans in the B field) rather than about how they achieve that.

Comment: I doubt if even radiologists can answer this. It's more of an engineering question than a medical question.

Comment: The only thing I can contribute is that axial slices are the most standard view for reviewing CT and MRI imaging.

Answer (score 0):

An MRI needs a really strong static magnetic field for contrast on the image.. You can achieve such a strong field with a lot of coil windings, and passing a current through those coils. In modern devices the coils are also kept in a superconductive state to decrease losses: http://mriquestions.com/types-of-magnets.html

The closed bore layout is just the most cost-effective way to attain that high magnetic field. If we put it sideways we can easily add a moving table so the patient can just lay there. A vertical coil layout wouldn't be too comfortable for the patient.